# Calculate centrality measures(betweenness, degree, closeness and eigencentrality using python igraph

Tags: python, r, igraph

I'm trying to convert this R code to python :

```
df_score <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mygraphs, function(gr){
    gr_deg <- centr_degree(gr)$centralization
    gr_bet <- centr_betw(gr, directed = FALSE)$centralization
    gr_clo <- centr_clo(gr, mode = "all")$centralization
    gr_eig <- centr_eigen(gr)$centralization

    #collect results in a data frame:
    df <- data.frame(betweenness=gr_bet, degree=gr_deg, closeness = gr_clo, eigen = gr_eig)
  })
)
```

where mygraphs is :

```
# Define a dictionary of graphs
mygraphs = {"full": gr_full,
            "tree": gr_tree,
            "rnd_25": gr_rnd_25,
            "rnd_50": gr_rnd_50,
            "rnd_75": gr_rnd_75,
            "rnd_100": gr_rnd_100,
            "rnd_200": gr_rnd_200}
```

I have tried various things but thet don't seem to be working. could someone please help me convert this R code to python using igraph?

The output should be similar to this:
betweenness     degree   closeness     eigen
full    0.000000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000
tree    0.599364080 0.02040404 0.235329206 0.7833769
rnd_25  0.001588759 0.02525253 0.000855427 0.9830214
rnd_50  0.027237954 0.04040404 0.003657573 0.9509750
rnd_75  0.125037220 0.04545455 0.009697238 0.9500023
rnd_100 0.260428791 0.04040404 0.027089542 0.8168838
rnd_200 0.072028210 0.05050505 0.064183952 0.6617146

```
df_degree = []

# loop through the dictionary of graph objects and calculate degree centrality for each graph
for gr_name, mygr in mygraphs.items():
    gr_cen = mygr.degree()
    # collect results in a dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'graph': [gr_name] * len(gr_cen), 'value': gr_cen})
    df_degree.append(df)

# merge dataframes into one
df_degree = pd.concat(df_degree)
```

I already did this but I dont know if this different from the given R code.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of valid R code, including graph definitions, ideally using `dput()`. Then that code can be converted into 'Python' style R, from which it is trivial to convert to Python.

Comment: `centr_...` functions, such as `centr_betw()` or `centr_degree()`, compute _centralization_, not centralities. This is a single number for the graph. In Python you are using `.degree()`, which computes a value for each vertex (the degree of each vertex).